# "You never know until you try"?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, psychology

Is it not possible to know our preferences for sure until we try? Do we have to try eating things to know whether or not we actually dislike the foods? Where does this saying stop? Do we have to try e.g. stealing things to know whether or not we actually dislike e.g. theft?

Comment: Theft isn't wrong because we don't want to steal. Theft is wrong, most ethical people claim, because it is immoral. Even early Buddhists - who are arguably complete hedonists - say that the valence of an action does not determine its value, its result etc..

Comment: You don't know if smashing your thumb with a hammer is painful or not until you try it. Or you can trust in common sense and avoid pain. Same with theft, you can trust common sense, avoid stealing and keep your freedom and possibilities of commercial interaction.

Comment: It is not possible to know our preferences "for sure" even after we try. Just because we liked/disliked something once does not guarantee that we will the next time. But it helps us make better educated guesses. And we can often make those guesses without trying too, if enough information is available second hand. Like most sayings, this one is not a direct guide to action, it does not "start" or "stop" anywhere in particular. It quips an obvious observation that trying delivers extra knowledge, it does not say whether that is enough to make the trying worthwhile.

Comment: @RodolfoAP Yes, you "know" hitting your thumb with a hammer is going to be painful by application of "common sense", but you don't actually *know what it feels like* until you *actually do it*, and can compare its qualitative nature with, e.g. being kicked in the nads, or having hot wax dripped on your sensitive spots, or having a piece of metal rotating at speed to make holes in your teeth (yeah, yeah, I know the drill). All these are painful, but all have a different *quality* of pain that the adventurous may apparently wish to explore.

Comment: @PrimeMover: "you don't actually know what it feels like until you actually do it". Under such standpoint, knowledge is not "actually" possible. You don't "actually" know what 1+1 gives until you "actually" calculate it.

Comment: @RodolfoAP So you're not a mathematician then? I *do* know that $1 + 1 = 2$ and I am able to prove this because I *am* a mathematician. If you are unable to do so, then indeed, you have to take it on faith.

Comment: @PrimeMover "...because I _am_ a mathematician": _argumentum ab auctoritate_. And a lot of _ego_.

Comment: @RodolfoAP Quite. Philosophy without mathematics is directionless.

Comment: My experience with this saying is twofold. If I talk about being gay, sometimes someone will be like, "But have you ever tried having sex with women?" If I talk about never having sex at all, they're like, "But so are you sure you're gay?" I have not found out whether I'd enjoy punching these people in the face, seeing as I have yet to punch them.

Comment: According to phenomenologists, to some extent for many things you don't need to try posteriori since there's some a priori intersubjective worldlife and salient landscape horizon. Phenomenology has such magic a priori perceivable and conceivable experiences and you may try to learn it...

Comment: Just to be obnoxious: you can't know even if you do try, because every event in spacetime is different, although people tend to classify events into sets for convenience. In other words, you may try thievery today and not enjoy it, but that doesn't mean you won't enjoy thievery another day.

Answer (score 2):

You kinda have to define what you mean by "you (never) **know**" in that statement. Like if you go to the abstract logic then there are things that you can know without trying them. If you go to the scientific knowledge then you truth is out the window and you actually would need to try it, but you can at least make predictions and formulate expectations of what might happen with some level of accuracy.

Though what this is likely about is more like "You will never know (how it makes you feel) until you try it". And that is likely true. Feelings are subjective, fuzzy, superpositioned with other feelings and therefore hard to predict or anticipated.

I mean there have been thousands of libraries been written about love but it's still more likely that you have an idea what they've written after you've experienced it, then having an idea of what it feels like after having read about it.

So it's probably hard to estimate how something is going to make you feel without trying it. And even if you did experience it, in a different setting and combination of hormones things might still be different as well.

Though you might be able to anticipate a quality of feelings. Like you could rank it in the pleasant or unpleasant domain. Like if you smash your thumb with a hammer that is likely going to be unpleasant. Though if it's not a solitary act but an accident while building something then the adrenaline and the feeling of accomplishment might numb the pain sufficiently to not feel it as unpleasant as it would be without them. Or take team sports where technically you're exercising pretty hard, but practically you don't even see it as exercises at all because you're busy playing a game. You might even experience pain as pleasure because it signifies that you gave it your best and when that lead to winning the game you've a positive association with something that would otherwise be negative. So even a qualitative prediction in the abstract might sometimes fail you.

However there are things where you can qualitatively already say that you don't WANT to know how that feels. Like idk dying, being dismembered, severely injured, to name just a few physical ones. So you might not know how it feels to steal, but you could already reason that the other person doesn't like it and that people around you don't like it if they have to fear for their stuff and so that you likely will face consequences for that. So yeah you still don't know if you don't try, but do you really want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Whether theft is wrong or not is irrelevant.

You can **truly** never know what it is like to experience something until you have experienced it.

I believe there *are* no limits to the underlying nature of the question.

But whether we decide to see what it is like to experience something which, for whatever reasons, our rational facilities tell us it is unwise to do, is ultimately up to us.

There are, for example, a number of experiences that are illegal (for example, what does ingesting this or that drug feel like?) which an unadventurous soul would not trouble to try, but which someone with more or less contempt for artificial political limits on what is or is not acceptable is far more amenable to testing.

Full comprehension of this point may help us understand how to find out why habitual killers do what they do. It is beyond doubt that some people *have* committed murder in order to "see what it's like", and decided they like it.

Comment: How would commiting a theft tell you, from experience, whether theft is right or wrong?

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas That's not what the question is about. Please read the first line of my post.

Answer (score 0):

"Never try, never know" is not a philosophical trueism, it's a attempt to coerce people to try something outside their comfort zone. It can be categorized as a statement belonging to hedonism, the pursuit of happiness by seeking pleasure, and could be seen as a simplified single statement version of hedonism.

As such, it does not stand to philosophic rigour, we can reliably predict things we will not enjoy, and we can make a moral, esthetic or otherwise justified choice not to try out things we might potentially enjoy.

There are many other fallacies surrounding the saying, such that there are infinite things that we could experience, but only finite time in mortal life, and no obvious way to prioritize all untried things. A lot of life experiences also involve long term involvements, such as "try being married for 20 years without cheating" which would reduce the ability to maximize attempts to try out things, but might still maximise happiness.

It can rather be seen as simplified informal life advice to seek one's own path in life not just living up to expectations, and not being quick to judge others just because they make experiences we deny ourselves.

But it is not formally justified enough to even start reason about it further, it is more suited to a fortune cookie than to a book on philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the saying is not completely correct. We can know if we like things without having to try them by ourselves. For example, by valuing the consequences on others who have tried them. If the consequences are not valued by us, we know we don't like to do that.

For example, theft, or crime in general, is avoided deliberately by people because they don't like the consequences, thus they don't like the act which leads to them.

Another way to know something without trying it, is by analogy. For example, we can know that hitting our thumbs with a hammer is going to be very painful because we have hit our fingers before less severely and we experienced pain, thus can estimate the amount of pain by analogy with a harder hit.

Comment: Old saying: Clever people learn from their mistakes. Wise people learn from other people’s mistakes.